# Como permitir login no sistema validando usuario e senha pelo banco de dados em php?

Tags: php, html

Galera seguinte: eu tenho um formulario html onde eu pego esses dados e envio para um action php onde os dados são processados e enviados para o banco de dados.  Essa parte está ok, os dados vão certinho e tudo mais. Agora eu tenho outra tela html de login. Essa tela o action é encaminhado para um php validacao.php onde o codigo é:

```
<?php
```

session_start();

```
//INICIA A CONEXÃO COM O BANCO DE DADOS
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "meuUsuario";
$password = "minhaSenha";
$dbname = "meuBanco";

$conexao = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conexao) {
    die("Não foi possível conectar ao banco de dados" . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['usuario']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, md5($_POST['senha']));

// Validação do usuário/senha digitados
$sql = "SELECT id, Nome, Senha FROM cadastroMorador WHERE Usuario = '$usuario' AND Senha = '$senha' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
if ($query) {
    // Mensagem de erro quando os dados são inválidos e/ou o usuário não foi encontrado
    $row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    if(password_verify($senha, row_usuario['Senha'])){
       header("Location: index.html");

    } else {
    echo "Login inválido!";
    header("Location: signin.html"); 
    }


} else {
    echo "Login inválido!";
    //header("Location: signin.html"); 


// Se a sessão não existir, inicia uma
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
// Salva os dados encontrados na sessão
$_SESSION['UsuarioID'] = $resultado['id'];
$_SESSION['UsuarioNome'] = $resultado['nome'];
//$_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'] = $resultado['nivel'];
// Redireciona o visitante

}
```

?>

Pelo que percebi ao tentar acessar ele não está comparando a senha com a senha que está com banco de dados (eu usei aquele md5, sei que não é recomendável mas não sei ainda alterar para fazer da forma correta). Acredito que o problema está aí. Alguém por favor pode me ajudar? Não consigo fazer login porque a senha não é comparada com a senha que está no banco de dados.

Comment: Não faz sentido incluir a senha na query e usar password_verify ao mesmo tempo. Se você grava um hash da senha no banco, não inclua a senha digitada na query de consulta, só o usuário. Aí esse código deve funcionar, contanto que a senha tenha sido gerada com [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Comment: @bfavaretto aí é que tá, a senha não foi gerado com password_hash(); Vou tentar arrumar isso e fazer a alteração aqui para ver se dá certo.

Comment: É mais seguro gerar com password_hash mesmo, MD5 que você mencionou nunca deve ser usado para senhas. Mas se precisar acessar alguma coisa já salva, gere o hash MD5 da senha que é informada no login e na query compare esse hash com o valor do banco. Se a query retornar um registro para o par usuário + hash, pode considerar válido o login.

Comment: @bfavaretto consegui gerar a senha pelo password_hash(). Olhei no banco e está gerado corretamente. Agora como eu devo alterar no meu código acima para ficar correto?

Comment: Tire esta parte da query: `AND Senha = '$senha'`

Comment: Tirei,  e continua dando erro. Ele entra no else e dá "Login Inválido". Quando eu mando a senha para o banco eu to mandando assim:  $senha = password_hash($_POST["senha"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $confirmarSenha = password_hash($_POST["ConfirmarSenha"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT); Desse jeito está indo para o banco com hash.  @bfavaretto

Comment: Tira o md5 lá de cima também. Não tinha visto ele lá.

Comment: Tirei, continua dando o mesmo erro. Não consigo achar o que pode ser.

Comment: Coloque nessa linha assim: **$query = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conexao));** ele vai indicar o erro.